# Getting a bunch of compile errors when testing create a react library using Typescript

Tags: typescript, npm, webpack

I am attempting to create my first NPM library. So i have approached t the same way i approach most of my projects which is to just write the code then try and error till it works. So i have created most of the code. Then i have linked my library using `npm link` and installed it in a test project using `npm link react-daraja`

I have a bunch of questions.

1. Do i have to compile my library before hand. So that the code that is pushed to NPM is just "ready". To expound i mean that when i used npm link i noticed in my node-modules folder its like the source files were directly copy pasted from my library source code to the target node modules folder. Is that how all other libraries work?

Question Two.
I got an error using my current approach.

```
../react-daraja/index.ts
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (31:13)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| 
| export const initializeApp = async (
>   initOptions: InitOptions
| ): Promise<InitializeAppResponse> => {
|   const { consumerKey, consumerSecret } = initOptions;
```

So question is. What the hell is that?? I cant even get myself to understand it.

Here is what i tried. I installed webpack to my project then pre-compiled it to a dist folder. But that didnt seem to fix the error. I still get the error when trying to use the library. So what do i do. Should i unlink then link my library again? My library was built to ensure type-safety. will bundling the code to a bundle.js be counter-productive? Please help.

Here is the link to my library so far. If you feel like you have the time on you hands you can make the cchanges and submit a PR i will be grateful.

https://github.com/amosmachora/react-daraja